# How to open the restricted site if request is coming from the particular server

Tags: java, facebook, firewall

Is it possible to create some defination in firewall to open the restricted site (say facebook) if it is coming from the server where our application is hosted but restrict from anywhere else.
ie.say our application is hosted on 172.0.0.0 ,if client request is coming from this server it would allow to open fb else it not allow. is it possible to create such defination.

Comment: I would have to say yes. For a more detailed answer you need to supply more information.

Comment: i have one link in my web application ,on the click of that link i am calling the servlet within the servlet which is deploy on application server i am redirecting the response to facebook.com ,so i want to allow opening facebook if request is coming from this server which is having some ip.

Comment: A redirect is something that is happening client-side – so the client will make the request for facebook.com if it is redirected there. And that means checking _“if request is coming from this server”_ is not an option, because the request __is not__ coming from the _server_.

Comment: hi CBroe , but firstly request goes to servlet from there i am redirecting to facebook,thus it is hitting the app server first

Comment: Any suggestion ,its require urgently..